# Does our word for [wrist] watch come from the 1735 English Longitude Prize?

Tags: etymology

[Neil DeGrasse Tyson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_deGrasse_Tyson) writes in the book [Death By Black Hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_Black_Hole) on page 314:

> In 1735, the Board of Longitude's challenge was met by a portable, palm-sized clock designed and built by an English mechanic, John Harrison. Declared to be as valuable to the navigator as a live person standing watch at a ship's bow, Harrison's chronometer gave renewed meaning to the word "watch".

The 'challenge' was the [longitude prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_prize). This was a sum of £20,000 put up by the Admiralty after 2000 sailors perished at sea due to poor navigation.

My question is: **Does our word for [wrist] watch come from the 1735 English Longitude Prize?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not. The word *watch* referring to a small timepiece predates 1735 by a good margin. The earliest citations in the [OED article](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226075) (sense 21a) are from the 16th century:

> **1590**   R. Harvey *Plaine Percevall* sig. D4<sup>v</sup>:
>   Surrender vp thy watch though it were gold.
>
> **1592**   R. Greene *Thirde Pt. Conny-catching* sig. E2<sup>v</sup>:
>   He reported his freend had lost a watch of golde: shewing how closely his freende wore it in his bosome.

The meaning seems to have been originally an alarm device attached to a clock, keeping *watch* of the time, as it were, for you. The earliest, though somewhat doubtful, citation for this sense is (sense 19):

> **c1440**   *Promptorium Parvulorum* 520/1:
>   Wecche, of a clokke.

Of course, none of these refers specifically to *wrist* watches, which are a slightly later thing. But once wrist watches became a thing, the word *watch* was already being applied to timepieces; there was no need to invent a new word.

Answer (score 2):

As a concept ( an arm watch at first) it appears to have an earlier origin, but as a noun it looks like that it started to be used around the end of the 19th century.

> - [Wrist-watch](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wrist) is from 1889. (Etymonline)

Wristwatch:

> - **The concept of the wristwatch goes back to the production of the very earliest watches in the 16th century.** Elizabeth I of England received a wristwatch from Robert Dudley in 1571, *described as an arm watch* From the beginning, wrist watches were almost exclusively worn by women, while men used pocket-watches up until the early 20th century.
> - **Wristwatches were first worn by military men towards the end of the 19th century**, when the importance of synchronizing manoeuvres during war, without potentially revealing the plan to the enemy through signalling, was increasingly recognized.
> - **The Garstin Company of London patented a 'Watch Wristlet' design in 1893, but they were probably producing similar designs from the 1880s.** Officers in the British Army began using wristwatches during colonial military campaigns in the 1880s, such as during the Anglo-Burma War of 1885. During the Boer War, the importance of coordinating troop movements and synchronizing attacks against the highly mobile Boer insurgents became paramount, and the use of wristwatches subsequently became widespread among the officer class. The company Mappin & Webb began production of their successful 'campaign watch' for soldiers during the campaign at the Sudan in 1898 and ramped up production for the Boer War a few years later. (Wikipedia)

[NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrist%20watch%2Cwrist-watch%2Cwristwatch&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrist%20watch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwrist%20-%20watch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwristwatch%3B%2Cc0) - wristwatch, wrist-watch, wrist watch.